# Java IDE for GUI development

Tags: java, class, user-interface, ide, bluej

I have developed some classes in Java and am wanting to develop a GUI to use these classes. My question is this: Is there an IDE for Java to create an easy GUI interface? Or is it basically writing code that can just be done via BlueJ.

Comment: Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/quick_start).

Answer (score 4):

Go for [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

> is a powerful and easy to use bi-directional Java GUI designer

WindowBuilder is composed of SWT Designer and Swing Designer and makes it very easy to create Java GUI applications without spending a lot of time writing code.

Comment: +1 for quoting the title :D

Comment: just be careful with SWT. The way SWT components are handled differs extensively from the standard AWT or Swing. And often you end up *exporting* the whole SWT library for every different platform – making your project platform dependent again.

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans and IntelliJ idea have some nice gui designers, but I personally think it's much better to write GUI forms by hand. When you'll need some finetuning later, you may find it hard with generated code.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good IDEs for Java. The most common are [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). Personally I would recommend NetBeans (just a matter of taste). It comes directly with a GUI builder where you can drag and drop your Swing components into the right position and add Actions you want to execute on the components. Also the genereated code is clean and easy to read. Just be careful when altering the generated code (deactivated by default) because it would mean that the gui builder might not be able to continue to read it.

Comment: I prefer window builder because you can write gui code first or make custom components, etc and it will still parse them into the visual editor.

Comment: yes, I added the "be careful" part, because it is (as always) possible to mess up the code. But normaly you don't run into any problems with NetBeans. And you can create your own components, too! But after all it may be just a matter of taste

Comment: God no! NetBeans generates god awful code. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but it uses only one layout manager (GroupLayout), while Eclipse WB can use multiple. Even some third party layout managers.

Comment: You have all kinds of different layout managers in Netbeans by default (and you can easily switch from one layout to another). And yes, generated code is almost always aweful :) – you have to change some settings so the code is generated in a way you like it. But nothing beats self written code!

Comment: +1 I agree about last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You have it in NetBeans by default (for Swing).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, NetBeans has some interface to drag and drop UI components, although I personally have not used it in quite some time. You could have a look at that maybe.